# Struct state handling

Tags: ios, swift, struct

For a sample struct :

```
struct Profile {
 var firstName: String?
 var lastName: String?
}
```

if I need to save the state of the struct based on user input (say tapping a save button) and then revert back to the last saved value (say tapping a cancel button), whats the best approach?

Should the struct be saved in a variable or as NSUserDefaults?

I created two variables, one to capture the change and update the other variable (one with old value) on save. And reset updated struct if cancel button is tapped and revert back to the last saved value.

`var initialState = Profile(firstName:"John",lastName:"Appleseed")`
capture changes on intialState

on save:

`var finalState = initialState`

on cancel:

`initialState = finalState`

If the user saves the first name from: John to Joey and then updates to Joeeee and cancels without saving. The variable should revert back to Joey

Comment: You can create an array of the struct if you want to revert multiple times, just remove the last object, then use the last object to show to user

Comment: I don't understand the need of declaring 2 variables, I think that 1 with the latest value should be enough? could you please elaborate?

Comment: In general, we create a profile object once view gets loaded & read values from saved instance.Now keep updating values in local instance of that class.Once user saves data, update your saved instance & refresh that local profile object too.